# Scala code - error: missing parameter type error

Tags: scala

What is wrong with this code?

```
object Numbers extends App {

  def decode(number: Int) : String = number match {
    case _ if _ % 15==0 => "fizzbuzz"
    case _ if _ % 3==0 => "fizz"
    case _ if _ % 5==0 => "buzz"
    case _ => _.toString
  }

  val test = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
  test.map(decode).foreach(println)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: String
case _ if _%15==0 => "fizzbuzz"
```

Why the compiler does not know the parameter type?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(_ % 15 == 0)` is expanded to a function `(x: ?) => x % 15 == 0`. Same for the other `if` checks.
The compiler can't infer it because it has no information about the parameter, it's a fresh name with no relation to the previous underscore in `case _`.  So you can't use the underscore there to refer to the matched name, you have to actually assign it a name, as in `case x if x % 15 == 0`